# How to migrate storage from one contract to another?

Tags: smart-contracts

Can we migrate storage from one contract to another,if we get any issue in first contract?

Comment: Please give more context. Are you developing a contract that you plan to migrate later or are you dealing with an already running contract? Does your contract store a big map ?